# Best ways to diagnose elasticsearch issues?

Tags: elasticsearch

The question is a little broad, but I feel there is no one place that helps systematically diagnose elastic search issues. The broad categories could be :

- **Client**

  1. Query errors
  2. Incorrect Query Results
  3. Unexplained behaviors
- **Server**

  1. Setup issues
  2. Performance issues
  3. Critical errors
  4. Unexplained behaviors

Example for 1)a) would be to say, log the query string on the server ( reference to how to enable logging would be nice), install the inquistor plugin (link to github) and run the query string yourself. etc.

Comment: Elasticsearch exposes pretty much everything as an api. Just pick what you want to monitor for what concerns the server section, have a look at the cluster apis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very broad and to be honest I am not sure I can fully answer it, however I will tell you how we monitor and manage our cluster.

1 - We log [query logs and slow query logs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html#logging) to [graylog2](http://graylog2.org/) (it uses es under the hood) so we can easily see, report, and alert on all logging from our cluster. We can also view slow queries that have occurred.

2 - we send [es stats](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html) to [statsd](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/) and then graph that information in graphite. This way we can see things like cluster state, query counts, indexing counts, jvm stats, disk i/o, etc. All parsed from the [es stats api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html) and sent to statsd

3 - we use [fabric scripts](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/) to deploy/upgrade the cluster and manage plugin installation

4 - we use [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) and [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to run occasional performance tests against the cluster (are we getting slower over time, does the cluster deployment work?)

5 - we use [bigdesk](http://bigdesk.org/) and [head](http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/) plugins to keep an eye on the cluster and explore how it is doing.